# Which magic items use Charisma or boost Charisma?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, ability-scores

I'm trying to find relics that influence or are influenced by Charisma, but I cannot seem to find any.

What are the magic items that use Charisma or boost Charisma?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The *Tome of Leadership and Influence*, when read, permanently boosts Charisma and maximum Charisma by 2.

The *Ioun Stone (Leadership)* boosts your Charisma by 2, to a maximum of 20, while it orbits your head.

The Star card (from the *Deck of Many Things*) can boost your Charisma by 2, to a maximum of 24.

As far as I can determine, there are no other items that affect your Charisma.

Items that are affected by your Charisma is more complicated. There are a few magical items whose use involves making a Charisma check or a Charisma saving throw, but this isn't really using your Charisma as such. However, if you are a Charisma-based spellcaster, every item that mentions "your spellcasting ability" is referring to your Charisma. There are far too many of these to list.

Comment: Is there not a magic item that sets it to 19, like the _Headband of Intellect_ does for Intelligence and the rest of those items?

Comment: @Javelin You'd think so, wouldn't you? But no, there's not. We even have [a question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84521/15469) about it.

Answer (score 25):

#### Boosts to your charisma score

[Tome of Leadership and Influence](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/tome-of-leadership-and-influence) (DMG, pg. 208):

> If you spend 48 hours over a period of 6 days or fewer studying the book's contents and practicing its guidelines, your Charisma score increases by 2, as does your maximum for that score.

[Ioun Stone (Leadership)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ioun-stone) (DMG, pg. 177):

> Your Charisma score increases by 2, to a maximum of 20, while this marbled pink and green sphere orbits your head.

[Sword of Zariel](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/sword-of-zariel) (BG:DiA, pg. 226):

> Your Charisma score becomes 20, unless it is already 20 or higher.

[Deck of Many Things (Star)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/deck-of-many-things) (DMG, pg. 162):

> Increase one of your ability scores by 2. The score can exceed 20 but can't exceed 24.

[Deck of Several Things (Star)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/deck-of-several-things) (LLoK):

> Increase one of your ability scores by 2. The score can exceed 20 but can't exceed 24.

[Bag of Beans](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bag-of-beans) (DMG, pg. 152):

> A nest of 1d4 + 3 eggs springs up. Any creature that eats an egg must make a DC 20 Constitution saving throw. On a successful save, a creature permanently increases its lowest ability score by 1, randomly choosing among equally low scores. On a failed save, the creature takes 10d6 force damage from an internal magical explosion.

#### Bonus or Advantage to Charisma Saving Throws

[Far Gear](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/far-gear):

> While attuned to this device, you have a +1 bonus to Charisma saving throws, and you have advantage on Charisma (Intimidation) checks.

[Greater Silver Sword](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/greater-silver-sword) (MToF, pg. 89):

> While you hold the sword, you have advantage on Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma saving throws

[Mind Carapace Armor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/mind-carapace-armor) (VGtM, pg. 81):

> To its intended wearer, the armor grants advantage on Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma saving throws and makes its wearer immune to the frightened condition.

#### Advantage on a type of Charisma check

[Far Gear](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/far-gear):

> While attuned to this device, you have a +1 bonus to Charisma saving throws, and you have advantage on Charisma (Intimidation) checks.

[*Color* Dragon Mask](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/blue-dragon-mask) ([*The Rise of Tiamat* Online Supplement v. 0.2](https://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/dnd/RiseTiamatSupplementv0.2_Printer.pdf), pg. 4):

> You also have advantage on any Charisma check you make against [*color*] dragons.

[Mask of the Dragon Queen](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/mask-of-the-dragon-queen) (RoT, pg. 94):

> While you are attuned to and wear this mask, you can have any of the properties from any one mask.

[Charm of Plant Command](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/charm-of-plant-command) (GoS, pg. 229):

> For the duration of the spell, you also have advantage on Charisma checks made to influence the behavior, demeanor, and attitude of plants.

[Perfume of Bewitching](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/perfume-of-bewitching) (XGtE, pg. 138):

> For the duration, you have advantage on all Charisma checks directed at humanoids of challenge rating 1 or lower.

[Belt of Dwarvenkind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/belt-of-dwarvenkind) (DMG, pg. 155):

> You have advantage on Charisma (Persuasion) checks made to interact with dwarves.

[The Bloody End](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/the-bloody-end) (EGtW, pg. 278):

> While holding the morningstar, you have advantage on Charisma (Intimidation) checks.

[Book of Exalted Deeds](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/book-of-exalted-deeds) (DMG, pg. 222):

> Once you’ve read and studied the book, you gain a protective halo. This halo sheds bright light in a 10-foot radius and dim light for an additional 10 feet. You can dismiss or manifest the halo as a bonus action. While present, the halo gives you advantage on Charisma (Persuasion) checks made to interact with good creatures and Charisma (Intimidation) checks made to interact with evil creatures.

[Book of Vile Darkness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/book-of-vile-darkness) (DMG, pg. 222):

> The mark of darkness grants you advantage on Charisma (Persuasion) checks made to interact with evil creatures and Charisma (Intimidation) checks made to interact with non-evil creatures.

[Uncommon Glamerweave](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/uncommon-glamerweave) (E:RftLW, pg. 277):

> When you make a Charisma (Performance) or Charisma (Persuasion) check while wearing the uncommon version of glamerweave, you can roll a d4 and add the number rolled to the check. Once you use this property, it can’t be used again until the next dawn.

[The Infernal Machine of Lum the Mad](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/the-infernal-machine-of-lum-the-mad) (IMR, pg. 96):

> Multiple random beneficial properties affect various charisma checks.

[Deck of Several Things (Comet)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/deck-of-several-things) (LLoK):

> If you single-handedly defeat the next hostile monster or group of monsters you encounter, you have advantage on ability checks made using one skill of your choice for the duration of the adventure. Otherwise, this card has no effect.

Comment: You left out "be a gnome" I think. (Or an item that can turn you into a gnome?)

Comment: I believe one item you missed is rolling 81-90 on the Bag of Beans while Charisma is your lowest ability score

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most common use for charisma in items has to do with sentient weapons. Charisma checks are used when the item doesn't agree with its usage by the wielder and can try to (essentially) charm the wielder if the wielder can't come to an agreement.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I don't think I can quote the books without violating copyright (although if that's wrong I'll amend my answer) but there is a little more to it.

Comment: @JimB: Generally, it's fine to quote only as much as is needed to answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

While it doesn't boost Charisma, the **Rod of the Pact Keeper** (very rare magical item) provides warlocks with a couple of the key benefits of having a higher CHA: +3 to spell attack rolls and spell save DC.

Comment: I feel like this would only be relevant of OP had indicated that they were looking at Charisma related items *for a Warlock*. An interesting find, but not really a good answer for this question.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the items you are looking for are very rare.
If it is a lower level character 5-10, a ring of spell storing is considered rare and can help a bit with spell casters for spell slots. Not as glamorous, but effective.

> Ioun Stone of Leadership. *Wondrous Item, very rare (requires attunement).*
>   Tome of Leadership and Influence. *Wondrous Item, very rare.*
>   The Deck of Many things. *Wondrous Item, very rare.*