# How can I determine the spell save DC of a monster/NPC?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw, difficulty-class

I am currently DMing a 5e homebrew campaign, and I was looking at the Drow monster stat block.

They have innate spellcasting abilities and one of those spells is Faerie Fire. In the description, it states that the targets must make a Dex saving throw or be outlined in color.

How do I determine the DC that is needed to *pass* the Dex saving throw against the Drow's Faerie Fire spell? It is not stated, and I am just a bit confused as to how to arrive at this number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I determine the result of a Saving Throw?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100770/how-do-i-determine-the-result-of-a-saving-throw)

Comment: That question covers the DC for PCs. This is about monsters.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## DC 11

The Monster Manual entry for the [Drow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/drow) states under Innate Spellcasting (emphasis mine):

> The drow’s spellcasting ability is Charisma (**spell save DC 11**). It can innately cast the following spells, requiring no material components.

Generally, the spell save DC will be listed in a similar section for all monsters with Innate Spellcasting.

Comment: Ahhh Okay! I get that, so the DC is based on whatever their spellcasting ability is, so in this case for the Drow it's based on their Charisma arriving at 11. Now the monster that the spell was cast on must make a DEX saving throw of at least 11. I think what was throwing me was I was thinking of it in terms of basing it on that ability, like it's a DEX saving throw so I was thinking what is the DEX DC calculation. Thank you again so much!!

Comment: @AaronFeuerstein Right, the Dex bit is for whomever is making the save.

Answer (score 17):

## DC 11

Typically a spell save DC is 8 + spellcasting ability modifier + proficiency bonus (PHB p205). In the case of the Drow that would be 8 + 1 + 2 = 11.

Proficiency bonus is based on the creature's CR. There's a chart in the Monster Manual (p8) that you can use to check it.

However. I don't know what version of the Monster Manual you're reading because both of mine (Yes I have two, I'm a nerd) state the spell save DC for the drow at the start of the "innate spellcasting" section.

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] for further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: +1, but you're going to need way more versions of the Monster Manual to establish nerd cred with this crowd.

Answer (score 4):

The saving throw DC for a monster with a spellcasting ability is stated in the stat block of the monster. It's in the details your eyes naturally gloss over between the bolded name of the feature and the spell list.

Comment: Love the mention of eyes glossing over. I've often missed important information because of that. But, you didn't actually answer the question...

Comment: @CasualViking Actually, he did answer the question. The question wasn't asking what the save DC was, it was asking how to find it.

Comment: More accurately, they asked how to find it and described the situation as one where it's not stated. Responding with "it is stated" isn't an answer.